# error " transport unknown" in Sails run on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, socket.io, sails.js

i'm writing sails app, when i run app on firefox, everything is ok, but when i run on chrome have error " transport unknown ".
My config socket.js:

> transports: ['websocket','flashsocket', 'polling','htmlfile','xhr-polling','jsonp-polling']

i don't why and how to fix, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

did you tried this one? Not working for me but I am on sails 0.11.1 ...
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2529

(from the git hub ticket)
modify the config/socket.js as follows:

```
transports: [
  'websocket',
  'htmlfile',
  'xhr-polling',
  'jsonp-polling'
]
```

to the following

```
transports: [
  'websocket',
  'htmlfile', 
  'polling'
],
```

Comment: Please add relevant information from the link to your answer as links can die.

Comment: If you migrating from < 0.11 don't forget to generate your new sails.io.js! https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/0.11-migration-guide.md

Comment: @JackWhiteIII thanks for mention this! `sails generate sails.io.js --force`